# How to create call back API in parse to get json response from external API?

Tags: android, json, api, parse-platform

Hello Stackoverflow developers. 
I m new to parse and integrating third party services via PHP API, currently i m able to post data and get response from PHP API's. But third party needs a call back API (from myside) on which they give confirmation response in JSON form.

Now i m totally confused how to make a API in parse which receives JSON response.
Please suggest me some methods or solutions for this

Thanks for providing me solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an interface say REsponseListener which has two methods onSuccess and OnFailure. You can also

Implement these methods where you are parsing the data.

If you receive a successful  API response, call onSucess otherwise call OnFailure.

In onSuccess, you can call the confirmation API.

Comment: But i have to give link of API which receives JSON response. Don't know where to create it on Parse Platform

Comment: I havent used ParsePlatform. may be you need to research a bit on the net. change the tag to Parse.